# Refer files from storage account in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

I have this following code where i need to refer my `ADF` codes stored in azure blob storage

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "https://adfcicdazurestorage82.blob.core.windows.net/adfcicdazurestorage82" -filter "*LinkedService*")
{
  New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADFAutomationResource" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD190218" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
```

These lines of code throw an error. I need to get these files from azure blob storage and create linked service.

Comment: Could to show the exact that is thrown? I would guess that Get-ChildItem throws an error because it cannot read an URL like this?

Comment: yes  it throws the below error.
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist. I have my ADF files in Azure BLOB Storage and need to refer in my above powershell

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Linked Service JSON File](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-powershell.md#create-a-linked-service-for-an-azure-storage-account) that links to your storage account.

Your code could look something like this:

```
#PowerShell:

New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADFAutomationResource" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD190218"  -File .\AzureStorageLinkedService.json | Format-List
```

...and your linked service JSON file like this *(filename: AzureStorageLinkedService.json)*:

```
     {
        "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
        "properties": {
            "type": "AzureStorage",
            "typeProperties": {
                "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=adfcicdazurestorage82;AccountKey=<accountkey>"
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: no im not looking for this..Im trying to automate by build using VSTS..in the release definition  i will call this powershell script which will deploy artifacts to the azure subscription..this powershell script has to refer files stored in azure blob storage and deploy it to a subscription..hope its clear